# Steel bracket fixing spacers on a wall

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structures, fasteners, masonry

What could I do to address the uneven vertical wall (not plumb) behind the bottom of the steel bracket?

Would you fill in the gap with sand/cement and once dried tighten the bolt or use steel plates and spacers?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Best result needs both of your suggestions.
Looks like you have enough thread on the installed bolts, so inserting shims to suit the gap/s(drilled thin steel plates) is a high strength solution. The finished job can be cosmetically improved by rendering the wall to achieve a vertical face and conceal the shims. Form and function both satisfied!

Comment: Thanks, I took onboard the suggestion. Not to worry about the cosmetics because there will be cladding hiding the whole structure. Below a picture of the result.

Answer (score 1):

The proper/best way is to begin with installing the brackets over a wall that is plumb, which can be achieved by plastering. If you do not wish to remove and reinstall the already-in-place anchor rods, the best choice is to use the shim plate for the depressed areas, however, the final result is difficult to control, as the wall may contain both bumps and depressions in a random manner.

Another way is more tedious but with a guaranteed better result - determine a plumb plane that is level with, or slightly beyond, the highest bump, then install the brackets using both shim plates and non-shrink grout after setting the nuts in according to the plumb plane.

Comment: Thanks, I think I used the method you outlined in the second part of your post. See pics.

Comment: Looks good. Glad it works out.

Answer (score 1):

According to the suggestions, I share the result.

Hopefully, the load is distributed evenly against the concrete wall.

[image: Finished installation]
[image: Washer spacers to recreate a plumb plane]